# What is the notation $F(a, b; -c, d)$ for computer numbers?

Tags: numerical-methods, notation, computer-arithmetic

I've encountered the following question:

**Question**: Find the number of elements in the set of computer numbers $F(6, 7; -6, 7)$.

I haven't seen the notation $F(a, b; -c, d)$ and hence, can't solve the problem. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you encounter this question? And in what language? Are decimal numbers written with commas in your part of the world?

Comment: What's a "computer number"?

Comment: I saw this question in a math test. I don't know what does computer number mean, here. I thought maybe it's a common name and notation, but searched a lot in google, nothing found...